# Responsive header behaves strange

Tags: html, css

I design the appearance and layout of an web app, where the goal is a responsive design with as small changes (media queries) as possible for the different device sizes.

I have put together the smallest example I could think, where I show one header-div with one vcenter-div inside. (In practice, I have more inline-block-columns.) Anyway, I would like to vertical align (center) all div-inline-blocks. In the demo, I have one pseudo-inline-block in .header:before and another inline-block in .vcenter.

In the vcenter-block I have one Google logo image. With responsiveness in mind, I would like the Google-image to be 20% of the size of the .header-div (NOT the .header .vcenter-div, therefore no height is given on the .header .vcenter-div).

This sometimes work quite good, sometimes not! On JSFiddle, I have a demo where it does NOT work:
https://jsfiddle.net/cfneikter/sy5w69f1/7/

On another server, I have quite the SAME demo, where it DOES work:
https://app04.azurewebsites.net/test.html

This is driving me nuts. Both Safari and Google Chrome behaves the same. But what is the difference? :)

The CSS is quite easy:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    height: 20%;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cacaca;
}

.header:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.header .vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 35%;
    text-align: left;
    color: #acacac;
}

.header .vcenter img {
    height: 20%; /* why is percent isn't working (sometimes)!?*/
    width: auto;
}
```

And so is the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="vcenter">
        <img src="some_image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May be this meta tag is the issue <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">

Comment: Add height: 100% on vcenter div

Comment: The "fix" with 100% on .vcenter-div does not work as intended, since the Google-logo is shown at the top, I would like to vertical align it inside the header-area. But the flex-solution, as someone mentioned, is an adequate one.

Comment: Problem is solved. But quite strange behaviour. I am so curious what the difference is. :) The meta tag-difference didn't seem to warrant the behavior.

Comment: Yeah I am also very confused as to why is it behaving differently !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height: 100%` on vcenter div

```css
 
body, html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.header {
height: 20%;
font-size: 1.0em;
position: relative;
background-color: #cacaca;
}

.header .vcenter {
display: inline-block;
width: 35%;
text-align: left;
color: #acacac;
height: 100%;
}

.header .vcenter img {
height: 20%; /* why is percent isn't working!?*/
width: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <div class="vcenter">
  <img src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Another way of doing what you need using flex

```css
 
body, html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.header {
height: 20%;
font-size: 1.0em;
background-color: #cacaca;
}

.header .vcenter {
width: 35%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align: left;
color: #acacac;
height: 100%;
}

.header .vcenter img {
height: 20%; /* why is percent isn't working!?*/
width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
 <div class="vcenter">
  <img src="http://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At least the first case doesn't show the img vertically aligned.

Comment: Thanks, the flex-solution works quite fine! However, the "fix" with 100% on .vcenter-div does not work as intended, since the Google-logo is shown at the top, I would like to vertical align it inside the header-area.

Comment: @elena. Yeah i know that. I didnt try to fix it. I just tried to reduce the size of image in that answer.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNeikter let me check and get back to you

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNeikter Can you give me the fiddle link ?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma maybe you can remove the solution which doesn't work

Comment: @elena Done. Please check